# DNS resolution timeouts after upgrade to go1.5

Tags: go, dns, upgrade

After upgrading from go1.3 to go1.5.2, I have been experiencing DNS request timeouts in my connections which go through ResolveTCPAddr() API in net library. I dug a little deeper to see what's going wrong in go1.5 because there's was a mention of DNS resolution implementation change in release notes of go1.5.

https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#net

In go1.5, for DNS resolution of unknown address, there's first a UDP dial and then a TCP dial to make the DNS request.

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.5/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L134

Sometimes, the read on UDP conn for a dns request is timing out (which could be for whatever reason being UDP) and my connection establishment is terribly slowing down (1ms becomes 5sec sometimes) randomly.

This made me force --netcgo flag at compile time to revert to old behavior mentioned in the release notes. But I want to resolve this without have to force anything that's not default.

Is this a known issue? Did anybody else run into this? I also want to understand why its making a udp connection first and what it did earlier and what changed for this to act differently now.

Comment: Please try to the current version of Go first in case this is a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: I did. It did not get fixed in the go1.6.2 version.

Comment: FYI, you can force either resolver with the `GODEBUG=netdns=` setting without rebuilding (might need go1.6, I would avoid go1.5 by now anyway). It might be useful to force the Go resolver and get debug output with `GODEBUG=netdns=go+1` to see where it's timing out exactly.

Comment: I used that too, but it did not seem very useful. It just gives the strategy is that it is picking. I instrumented all the paths in go and recompiled to trace this api flow and figured that it times on this line.
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.5/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L44

Nothing changed in regard to this in 1.6

Comment: What is your system resolver doing differently when the DNS server times out? Was it racing resolution from multiple servers? Does it have a local cache so there were just fewer timeouts?